# Can't Pass StringTokenizer to more than one method

Tags: java, string

Though, I have done a workaround for this, but still this thing is confusing me, well logically.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            String sent = "He is doing it good";
            StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(sent);
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            secondMethod(st);       
            firstMethod(st);

            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println(t2-t1);

        }


        public static void firstMethod(StringTokenizer st)
        {
            System.out.println("in first");

            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());

            }


        }


        public static void secondMethod(StringTokenizer st)
        {

            System.out.println("in second");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());

            }       
        }




Output of above //
in second
He
is
doing
it
good
in first
```

//please avoid fine grain accuracy.

In the above code, I have realized that Java deletes st after first use. Like if I am calling firstMethod first, st passes well to the method and I can see the complete tokenized string, but nothing in secondMethod, and vice versa. Why so? Why can't I pass st to different methods ? New to Java, just curious what exactly this thing is called? Garbage collection?

Ahh, looks like I am asking too much on SO. I will try to find time to answer questions in capacity as well.

Comment: Have you looked at the api documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: okk, split() is new method here. Will use that only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `StringTokenizer` keeps an internal count of the amount of tokens it has used. The object doesn't start from the beginning when you pass it to another function. In your first method, you use all tokens..and it's at the end.

**Example**

```
"This is a string"
```

`^ - Position of Tokenizer before method.`

```
"This is a string"

                  ^ - Position of string tokenizer after method.
```

You pass the **same** object to another method, and the position is still at the end. Hence, no more tokens.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the same `StringTokenizer` object to both methods.  But you are using up all the tokens in whichever method is called first, because each method consumes all tokens in a `while` loop.  So the method that is called second has no more tokens and doesn't print any tokens.

Comment: got it. thanks. Is there any way I can avoid creating tokenizer object in every method?

Comment: It depends on what you're really trying to do.  Are you trying to re-parse the entire string in each method, or are you trying to parse part of it in one method and the rest in the other method?

Comment: re-parse entire string. It is suggested that use of StringTokenizer is not discouraged. I am moving to split() now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you are calling secondMethod() first and firstMethod() second?

Given that, the code appears to be operating normally.  secondMethod() processes all the tokens.  firstMethod() is called after all the tokens are processed, so nothing to do there.

In any case, the StringTokenizer object is not deleted in any sense throughout.  It is being passed around successfully, by reference, between main(), firstMethod(), and secondMethod().  It is true that it runs out of tokens, but, hey, it's just doing it's job.

If you want to convince yourself of that, just retrieve a couple tokens in the method you call first and pick up the remainder in the other one.  It will work.